# lato package unable removed from my "TeX Live Utility"

Tags: texlive, tex-live-utility

macOS High Sierra 10.13.4

I found my "TeX Live Utility (version 1.34)" update tab always shows only one item: "lato Forcibly removed", I guess it means that the update will remove this lato package. However, doing the update, which ends up with "update succeeded", when doing a refresh, or reopening the TeX live Utility, this item come up again. This issue remains for a couple of weeks.

I am using repository: http://mirrors.tuna.tsinghua.edu.cn/CTAN/systems/texlive/tlnet

Chaning repository does not help. What should I do?

Answer (score 1):

Select the offending package in the list, and choose **Reinstall Selected Packages** from the **Actions** menu. This can happen if the installer crashes during an update, or if you manually removed the package.